# @ResponseBody not working with spring 4.2.4 - not a duplicate I have checked all others

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

Here is my setup:

spring version: 4.2.4.RELEASE

Jackson libs:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

spring config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Request Object:

```
public class TagSearchCriteria {
    private String term;

    public void setTerm(String term){
        this.term = term;
    }

    public String getTerm(){
        return this.term;
    }
}
```

Response Object

```
public class TagSearchResponse {
    private String result;

    public void setResult(String result){
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getResult(){
        return this.result;
    }
}
```

And here is the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tagvalue.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody TagSearchResponse getTags(@RequestBody TagSearchCriteria tagSearchCriteria) {

        Tag tag = tagDao.getTags(tagSearchCriteria.getTerm());
        TagSearchResponse tagSearchResponse = new TagSearchResponse();
        tagSearchResponse.setResult(tag.getTagName());
        return tagSearchResponse;
    }
```

And finally here is my AJAX call

```
$("#tag").keyup(function() {
        var tagValue = $("#tag").val();
        if (tagValue.length > 2) {
            var data = {}
            data["term"] = $("#tag").val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                contentType : "application/json",
                url : "tagvalue.htm",
                data : JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType : 'json',
                timeout : 100000,
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
                    display(data);
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                    display(e);
                },
                done : function(e) {
                    console.log("DONE");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

what I get in response is 406 error

HTTP Status 406 - Status report
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

in controller, upto return tagSearchResponse; its all good and this return object is a valid object being returned

Comment: The jquery version is 1.12.2

Comment: Have you checked what the value of the request accept header is?

Comment: There are two values there. Application/json and javascript/text

Comment: None of those look like valid content types to me.

Comment: Hang on let me get the exact values

Comment: Accept 
application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Comment: Don't map your method to `tagvalue.htm`: extensions are used by Spring to determine what the client wants, and you clearly don't want htm, but json. Just map your method to tagvalue, and use tagvalue or tagvalue.json as URL.

Comment: value = "/tagvalue.htm" change this with value = "/tagvalue"

Comment: OMG!!!, I have wasted 4 days on this. why would @RequestMapping's value should define what user wants in the response, it doesn't make any sense, I thought they are JUST to map methods to requests. Is there any reason why is that?
making the above change made it work!

Comment: That's not how it works. By default, when you define a mapping for /foo, you can use /foo (and Spring will use the accept header to decide what's best to return), but you can also use /foo.json to request JSON specifically, of /foo.xml to request xml specifically, etc. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multiple-representations

Comment: Cool thanks! Thats a valueable learning of my whole career. Could u please put your comment as answer n i ll mark that as right answer to help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your mapping. By default, Spring uses the extension in the URL to decide what type of content to return (html, json, xml, etc.).

Your method is mapped to `/tagvalue.htm`, but you want it to return json (which is quite confusing, BTW).

Change the mapping to `/tagvalue`, and use `/tagvalue` or `/tagvalue.json` to reach the endpoint.

More information about this mechanism is available in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multiple-representations).